# Neo4Jphp installation and working Beginner

Tags: php, neo4j, installation, neo4jphp

I am a Beginner of Neo4J and wanted to use with php.
1. Downloaded Neo4Jphp https://github.com/jadell/Neo4jPHP
2. Unzipped at htdocs/abc/neo4php
3. Used Below code (at htdocs/abc/index.php) but getting ERROR -

```
Fatal error: Class 'neo4php\lib\Everyman\Neo4j\Client' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\abc\index.php on line 14
```

Code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Neo4J</h1>

<?php

use neo4php\lib\Everyman\Neo4j\Client,
    neo4php\lib\Everyman\Neo4j\Transport,
    neo4php\lib\Everyman\Neo4j\Node,
    neo4php\lib\Everyman\Neo4j\Relationship;

$client = new Client(new Transport('localhost', 7474));
$keanu = new Node($client);
$keanu->setProperty('name', 'Keanu Reeves')->save();
$laurence = new Node($client);
$laurence->setProperty('name', 'Laurence Fishburne')->save();
$jennifer = new Node($client);
$jennifer->setProperty('name', 'Jennifer Connelly')->save();
$kevin = new Node($client);
$kevin->setProperty('name', 'Kevin Bacon')->save();

$matrix = new Node($client);
$matrix->setProperty('title', 'The Matrix')->save();
$higherLearning = new Node($client);
$higherLearning->setProperty('title', 'Higher Learning')->save();
$mysticRiver = new Node($client);
$mysticRiver->setProperty('title', 'Mystic River')->save();

?>

</body>
</html>
```

How to solve the issue and access Neo4J using PHP, Is there any video tutorial for Neo4JPhp

Comment: What version PHP you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't including the library anywhere. In PHP, you can't just `use` classes, you have to include a file which contains that class, or use an autoloader that maps class names to file names (autoloading is the preferred way to do it.)

I suggest installing the library with Composer. There are instructions for this on the neo4jphp wiki: https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/wiki/Getting-started. (You will need to install Composer first; instructions available here: https://getcomposer.org/)

Then, in your file, you can do:

```
<?php
require('vendor/autoload.php');

use Everyman\Neo4j\Client,
    Everyman\Neo4j\Transport,
    Everyman\Neo4j\Node,
    Everyman\Neo4j\Relationship;

// The rest of your code
```

Comment: vendor/autoload.php directory is not created, So i used include("neo4jphp.phar") and its working- But I want to use autoload.php- I followed installation guide but directory is not created please help

Comment: Did you run composer from the same directory as your script file? The vendor directory will be created in whatever directory you ran composer from, and you will have to alter the `require` line to point to that directory. And don't use the PHAR file. It is out of date and deprecated.